# jsPDF issue when content takes more than 1 page (React, HTML) HTML TO PDF

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to print a PDF from HTML content that I have on a React application. What I do is, take an HTML container and do the following:

```js
      await htmlToImage
        .toPng(node)
        .then((dataUrl) => {
          const pdf = new jsPDF();
          const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(dataUrl);
          const imgWidth = imgProps.width;
          const imgHeight = imgProps.height;
          const ptWidth = ( imgWidth * 0.75 );
          const ptHeight = ( imgHeight * 0.75 );

          if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
            const finalPdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [ptHeight, ptWidth]);
            let pdfWidth = finalPdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            let pdfHeight = finalPdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

            finalPdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
            finalPdf.save(fileName);
          } else {
            const finalPdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [ptHeight, ptWidth]);
            let pdfWidth = finalPdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            let pdfHeight = finalPdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

            finalPdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
            finalPdf.save(fileName);
          }
        });
```

What ends up happening is that if the HTML content occupies more than 1 page, the script tries to send only 1 PDF page with just one image making the content impossible to read and not doing the end goal which is having a paginated PDF Form.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working solution in React

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

const div1 = document.getElementById('div1')

const xPos = 10
const yPos = 10
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')
const pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - (xPos * 2)

const margins = {
    top: 5,
    bottom: 0,
}

doc.fromHTML(div1, xPos, yPos, {
    'width': pageWidth,
}, function () {}, margins)

doc.save('filename')
```